# Edit custom taxonomy description programatically

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've added a custom taxonomy and I wanted to know if there is a way to edit a custom taxonomy's description.

Here's the description field. 
[image: image of custom taxonomy]

IS there a function that provides access to this field? And if so, would I be able to use it in the New Posts page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [`get_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) you can access the description via the `description` property. To update a term you can use [`wp_update_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term).